# Failed to set Datepicker's minimum date

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have CalenderVC which consist of Container View named PickerController.
PickerController consist of one toolbar,datepicker.Everytime i want to add date i use PickerController but 
my problem is on somecondition i also want to set minimum date.I also passed minimumdate using customdelegate but still datepicker not set minimum date.

```
//CalendarVC added PickerController

- (void)displayContentView
{
    UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Pagebar" bundle:nil];
    objContent=[story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pickerVCID"];
    objContent.datePicker.hidden=false;
    self.dtDelegate=objContent;
    objContent.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 280);
    if(isFromDate==false)
    {
        // delegate method that set minimum date of picker
        [self.dtDelegate setMinDate:minimumDate];
    }
    _pickerContainerVw.hidden=false;
    [self addChildViewController:objContent];
    [self.view addSubview:_pickerContainerVw];
    [objContent didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

-(void)removeContentView
{
    _pickerContainerVw.hidden=true;
    [objContent willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [objContent.view removeFromSuperview];
    [objContent removeFromParentViewController];
    objContent.view.hidden=true;
}

// In pickercontroller

-(void)setMinDate:(NSDate *)minDate
{  
    [self.datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
    [self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];
    NSLog(@"minimum date %@",minDate);    
}
```

Comment: Let me guess: In the line `[self.dtDelegate setMinDate:minimumDate];`, `objContent.datePicker` is nil?

Comment: no delegate method also called and execute perfectly .. that's not issue ...

Comment: So when `setMinDate` is called, `self.datePicker` is not `nil`?

Comment: No Mindate is also perfect.. i double checked it

Answer (score 0):

There are several potential problems with your code.

- First make sure you have connected your outlets in pickerVCID, especially `datePicker`.
- Then I wonder why you add the picker to the view pickercontroller in `setMinDate:`? Since you seem to have designed it as a storyboard view controller you already have it as a child in the correct view. In that case you can just hide/show it.
- Also, where do you set `_pickerContainerVw`? Is it the same as `objContent.view`? You are adding the `objContent`as a child view controller, but `_pickerContainervW` as sub-view. Probably you want to add the `objContent.view` as a sub-view instead.

With the risk of introducing side-effects with my changes, since I haven't seen all of your code, I have fixed some of the above.

```
//CalendarVC added PickerController

- (void)displayContentView
{
    // Instantiate picker
    UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Pagebar" bundle:nil];
    objContent=[story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pickerVCID"];
    self.dtDelegate=objContent;
    objContent.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width, 280);

    // Add it as a child VC
    [self addChildViewController:objContent];
    [self.view addSubview:objContent.view];
    [objContent didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    // Start with hidden date picker, show if needed    
    objContent.datePicker.hidden = YES;
    if(isFromDate==false)
    {
        // delegate method that set minimum date of picker
        objContent.datePicker.hidden = NO;
        [self.dtDelegate setMinDate:minimumDate];
    }
}

-(void)removeContentView
{
    [objContent willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [objContent.view removeFromSuperview];
    [objContent removeFromParentViewController];
}

// In pickercontroller

-(void)setMinDate:(NSDate *)minDate
{  
    [self.datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate];
    NSLog(@"minimum date %@",minDate);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer .. for 2nd point I use delegate to set minimumdate so it's needed .. but your 3rd point is totally valid i access parentviewcontroller property directly ..